# How to update and redeploy ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-rm-template

I am new to Azure as well as Devops, ARM template etc..I have deployed an ARM template for key valut with a name "ABC" via DevOPs. Now I would like to change some parameters. I don't have access to do it via portal and I am forced to use only ARM template. How can this be achieved via devops? Should I delete that resource and start from the scratch or any SOP to update resource parameters via ARM templates. For example I want to enable "“enabledForDeployment” for already deployed kay-vault. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it through PowerShell,

[`Update a resource in an Azure Resource Manager template`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/azure-resource-manager/advanced-templates/update-resource)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. We don't have any access to update via cloudshell or PowerShell. We are allowed to deploy ARM template only via Azure DevOps (by corporate design). Could you please suggest if there are any best practices? Thanks again.

Comment: if it's only via Azure DevOps, update your template and trigger the deployment

Comment: (unfortunately this is now a dead link)

Comment: link is updated or back?

Answer (score 3):

generally speaking you just re-run the same template with the changes you've introduced to the template. there are many ways of deploying the template (az cli, powershell, built-in steps, various sdk's).

just keep in mind, some properties are settable only at creation time, so effectively read only, you wouldn't be able to update those after the resource is created, some resource providers do not play well with idempotent behavior and this will also lead to issues when you try to redeploy the same template, some providers offer dodgy behavior when you need to use a completely different api call to update something compared to creating it.

So there's no single answer, but for what you are doing, just updating the template and running it again should work just fine.