# getting error "The schedule should be created" while creating VM shutdown schedule using ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I am getting the following error when I tried creating a shutdown schedule for VM in azure using the ARM template.

```json
{
  "code": "DeploymentFailed",
  "message": "At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.",
  "details": [
    {
      "code": "InvalidScheduleId",
      "message": "The schedule should be created in subscription xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx, resource group shared-infra-rc-rg and with name shutdown-computevm-xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-pg-rc."
    }
  ]
}
```

### Part of my ARM template

```json
{
            "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
            "apiVersion": "2019-03-01",
            "name": "[variables('vmName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "tags": {"envId":"[parameters('envId')]"},
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/', variables('networkInterfaceName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "hardwareProfile": {
                    "vmSize": "[parameters('VmSize')]"
                },
                "storageProfile": {
                    "osDisk": {
                        "createOption": "fromImage",
                        "managedDisk": {
                            "storageAccountType": "[variables('osDiskType')]"
                        }
                    },
                    "imageReference": {
                        "publisher": "Canonical",
                        "offer": "UbuntuServer",
                        "sku": "[parameters('ubuntuOSVersion')]",
                        "version": "latest"
                    }
                },
                "networkProfile": {
                    "networkInterfaces": [
                        {
                            "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', variables('networkInterfaceName'))]"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "osProfile": {
                    "computerName": "[variables('vmName')]",
                    "adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
                    "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPasswordOrKey')]",
                    "linuxConfiguration": "[if(equals(parameters('authenticationType'), 'password'), json('null'), variables('linuxConfiguration'))]",
                    "customData": "[parameters('customData')]"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "[variables('autoshutdownScheduleName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.DevTestLab/schedules",
            "apiVersion": "2018-09-15",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines', variables('vmName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "status": "[parameters('autoShutdownStatus')]",
                "taskType": "ComputeVmShutdownTask",
                "dailyRecurrence": {
                    "time": "[parameters('autoShutdownTime')]"
                },
                "timeZoneId": "[parameters('autoShutdownTimeZone')]",
                "targetResourceId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines', variables('vmName'))]",
                "notificationSettings": {
                    "status": "Disabled",
                    "notificationLocale": "en"
                }
            }
        }
```

### Other observations

- all other resources are getting created except the schedule.

### Edits

[image]

Comment: `InvalidScheduleId` -- It is the error received when a pet name was given to the schedule. Reference: [Adding Azure VM auto-shutdown via ARM template](https://joymonscode.blogspot.com/2017/07/adding-azure-vm-auto-shutdown-via-arm.html) and [Azure – The schedule should be created in subscription error in ARM Template deployment](https://knowledge-junction.com/2018/12/09/azure-the-schedule-should-be-created-in-subscription-error-in-arm-template-deployment/)

Comment: @DeepDave-MT I changed the name of the schedule but it is not reflected in deployment.

Comment: You can update and re-deploy the ARM template. [How to update and redeploy ARM template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57505831/how-to-update-and-redeploy-arm-template) and [Update a resource in an Azure Resource Manager template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/azure-resource-manager/advanced-templates/update-resource)

Comment: @DeepDave-MT As you can see in the image, an error is a resource with the name `shutdown-compute-*` but I changed the resource name to `prlteam-xxx`

Comment: Hello @PSKP, If the provided answer is helpful, you can accept it as an answer to help other community members for similar queries. Thank you.

Comment: I had same problem with powershell to create a autoshutdown today and @Ecstasy 's answer helped to to figure out the problem, but it's not immediately clear to me what "pet name" means. your problem should be in variables('autoshutdownScheduleName'), it need to be exact as "shutdown-computevm-${vmName}".  Is your VM named as xxx-pg-rc ?

Answer (score 1):

The name needs to be **exactly** `'shutdown-computevm-${vmName}'`

bicep sample:

```js
resource vmScheduledShutdown 'microsoft.devtestlab/schedules@2018-09-15' = {
  name: 'shutdown-computevm-${vmName}'
  location: Location
  properties: {
    status: 'Enabled'
    taskType: 'ComputeVmShutdownTask'
    dailyRecurrence: {
      time: '0400'
    }
    timeZoneId: 'Central European Standard Time'
    targetResourceId: resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines', vmName)
  }  
  dependsOn:[
    vm
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We have tried to ***create VM with  auto shutdown enabled*** using the below ***ARM template*** and we are able to ***deploy it successfully*** .

***ARM template*** :-

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
      "adminUsername": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
          "description": "Username for the Virtual Machine."
        }
      },
      "adminPassword": {
        "type": "secureString",
          "metadata": {
          "description": "Password for the Virtual Machine."
        }
      },
      "dnsLabelPrefix": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "[toLower(format('{0}-{1}', parameters('vmName'), uniqueString(resourceGroup().id, parameters('vmName'))))]",
        "metadata": {
          "description": "Unique DNS Name for the Public IP used to access the Virtual Machine."
        }
      },
      "publicIpName": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "myPublicIP",
        "metadata": {
          "description": "Name for the Public IP used to access the Virtual Machine."
        }
      },
      "publicIPAllocationMethod": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "Dynamic",
        "allowedValues": [
          "Dynamic",
          "Static"
        ],
        "metadata": {
          "description": "Allocation method for the Public IP used to access the Virtual Machine."
        }
      },
      "publicIpSku": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "Basic",
        "allowedValues": [
          "Basic",
          "Standard"
        ],
        "metadata": {
          "description": "SKU for the Public IP used to access the Virtual Machine."
        }
      },
      "OSVersion": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "2019-datacenter-gensecond",
        "allowedValues": [
          "2019-datacenter-gensecond",
          "2019-datacenter-core-gensecond",
          "2019-datacenter-core-smalldisk-gensecond",
          "2019-datacenter-core-with-containers-gensecond",
          "2019-datacenter-core-with-containers-smalldisk-g2",
          "2019-datacenter-smalldisk-gensecond",
          "2019-datacenter-with-containers-gensecond",
          "2019-datacenter-with-containers-smalldisk-g2",
          "2016-datacenter-gensecond"
        ],
        "metadata": {
          "description": "The Windows version for the VM. This will pick a fully patched Gen2 image of this given Windows version."
        }
      },
      "vmSize": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "Standard_D2s_v3",
        "metadata": {
          "description": "Size of the virtual machine."
        }
      },
      "location": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "metadata": {
          "description": "Location for all resources."
        }
      },
      "vmName": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "simple-vm",
        "metadata": {
          "description": "Name of the virtual machine."
        }
      },
      "autoShutdownStatus": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "Enabled"
        },
        "autoShutdownTime": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "19:00"
        },
        "autoShutdownTimeZone": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "UTC"
        },
        "autoShutdownNotificationStatus": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "Enabled"
        },
        "autoShutdownNotificationLocale": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "en"
        },
        "autoShutdownNotificationEmail": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "youremailID@microsoft.com"
        }
    },
     "variables": {
      "storageAccountName": "[format('bootdiags{0}', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]",
      "nicName": "myVMNic",
      "addressPrefix": "10.0.0.0/16",
      "subnetName": "Subnet",
      "subnetPrefix": "10.0.0.0/24",
      "virtualNetworkName": "MyVNET",
      "networkSecurityGroupName": "default-NSG"
    },
    "resources": [
      {
        "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
        "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
        "name": "[variables('storageAccountName')]",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "sku": {
          "name": "Standard_LRS"
        },
        "kind": "Storage"
      },
      {
        "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses",
        "apiVersion": "2021-02-01",
        "name": "[parameters('publicIpName')]",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "sku": {
          "name": "[parameters('publicIpSku')]"
        },
        "properties": {
          "publicIPAllocationMethod": "[parameters('publicIPAllocationMethod')]",
          "dnsSettings": {
            "domainNameLabel": "[parameters('dnsLabelPrefix')]"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups",
        "apiVersion": "2021-02-01",
        "name": "[variables('networkSecurityGroupName')]",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "properties": {
          "securityRules": [
            {
              "name": "default-allow-3389",
              "properties": {
                "priority": 1000,
                "access": "Allow",
                "direction": "Inbound",
                "destinationPortRange": "3389",
                "protocol": "Tcp",
                "sourcePortRange": "*",
                "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                "destinationAddressPrefix": "*"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
        "apiVersion": "2021-02-01",
        "name": "[variables('virtualNetworkName')]",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "properties": {
          "addressSpace": {
            "addressPrefixes": [
              "[variables('addressPrefix')]"
            ]
          },
          "subnets": [
            {
              "name": "[variables('subnetName')]",
              "properties": {
                "addressPrefix": "[variables('subnetPrefix')]",
                "networkSecurityGroup": {
                  "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', variables('networkSecurityGroupName'))]"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "dependsOn": [
          "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', variables('networkSecurityGroupName'))]"
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
        "apiVersion": "2021-02-01",
        "name": "[variables('nicName')]",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "properties": {
          "ipConfigurations": [
            {
              "name": "ipconfig1",
              "properties": {
                "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
                "publicIPAddress": {
                  "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', parameters('publicIpName'))]"
                },
                "subnet": {
                  "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', variables('virtualNetworkName'), variables('subnetName'))]"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "dependsOn": [
          "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', parameters('publicIpName'))]",
          "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', variables('virtualNetworkName'))]"
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
        "apiVersion": "2021-03-01",
        "name": "[parameters('vmName')]",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "properties": {
          "hardwareProfile": {
            "vmSize": "[parameters('vmSize')]"
          },
          "osProfile": {
            "computerName": "[parameters('vmName')]",
            "adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
            "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPassword')]"
          },
          "storageProfile": {
            "imageReference": {
              "publisher": "MicrosoftWindowsServer",
              "offer": "WindowsServer",
              "sku": "[parameters('OSVersion')]",
              "version": "latest"
            },
            "osDisk": {
              "createOption": "FromImage",
              "managedDisk": {
                "storageAccountType": "StandardSSD_LRS"
              }
            },
            "dataDisks": [
              {
                "diskSizeGB": 1023,
                "lun": 0,
                "createOption": "Empty"
              }
            ]
          },
          "networkProfile": {
            "networkInterfaces": [
              {
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', variables('nicName'))]"
              }
            ]
          },
          "diagnosticsProfile": {
            "bootDiagnostics": {
              "enabled": true,
              "storageUri": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName'))).primaryEndpoints.blob]"
            }
          }
        },
        "dependsOn": [
          "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', variables('nicName'))]",
          "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName'))]"
        ]
      },
        {
            "name": "[concat('shutdown-computevm-', parameters('vmName'))]",
            "type": "Microsoft.DevTestLab/schedules",
            "apiVersion": "2017-04-26-preview",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', parameters('vmName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "status": "[parameters('autoShutdownStatus')]",
                "taskType": "ComputeVmShutdownTask",
                "dailyRecurrence": {
                    "time": "[parameters('autoShutdownTime')]"
                },
                "timeZoneId": "[parameters('autoShutdownTimeZone')]",
                "targetResourceId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines', parameters('vmName'))]",
                "notificationSettings": {
                    "status": "[parameters('autoShutdownNotificationStatus')]",
                    "notificationLocale": "[parameters('autoShutdownNotificationLocale')]",
                    "timeInMinutes": "30",
                    "emailRecipient": "[parameters('autoShutdownNotificationEmail')]"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {
      "hostname": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', parameters('publicIpName'))).dnsSettings.fqdn]"
      }
    }
  }
```

Sample ***OUTPUT*** for reference:-
[image]

[image]

Auto shut down enabled:
[image]

For more information refer this [***MS Q&A***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/307098/virtual-machine-auto-shutdown-based-on-schedule-us.html) as suggested by [***JamesTran-MSFT***](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/users/2493538/jamestran-msft.html)